# AWS SDK Amazon S3 upload method spoils image file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

everybody here is my issue.
I wrote an AWS Lambda with the next code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

function getValueIgnoringKeyCase(object, key) {
    const foundKey = Object
        .keys(object)
        .find(currentKey => currentKey.toLocaleLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase());
    return object[foundKey];
}

function getBoundary(event) {
    return getValueIgnoringKeyCase(event.headers, 'Content-Type').split('=')[1];
}


module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
    const boundary = getBoundary(event);
    const result = {};
    event.body
        .split(boundary)
        .forEach(item => {
            if (/filename=".+"/g.test(item)) {
                result[item.match(/name=".+";/g)[0].slice(6, -2)] = {
                    type: 'file',
                    filename: item.match(/filename=".+"/g)[0].slice(10, -1),
                    contentType: item.match(/Content-Type:\s.+/g)[0].slice(14),
                    content: item.slice(item.search(/Content-Type:\s.+/g) + item.match(/Content-Type:\s.+/g)[0].length + 4, -4),
                };
            } else if (/name=".+"/g.test(item)){
                result[item.match(/name=".+"/g)[0].slice(6, -1)] = item.slice(item.search(/name=".+"/g) + item.match(/name=".+"/g)[0].length + 4, -4);
            }
        });

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result),
    };

    Promise.all(Object.keys(result)
        .filter(item => result[item].type === 'file')
        .map(item => (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            S3.upload({
                Bucket: 'try753',
                Key: result[item].filename,
                Body: Buffer.from(result[item].content),
            }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
            });
        }))))
        .then(() => {
            callback(null, response);
        });


};
```

In that function, I:

1. get multipart/form-data
2. extract data into an object 3)
3. save files to s3

but here is an issue,
I got an image file 50Kb, and after data extraction, I get Buffer 50Kb,
but when I save a file into s3, its size is 94Kb and it's spoiled.
What happens with it during s3.upload?
P.S. There are the same problems with any media file.
P.S.S. There is no problem with txt files.

Answer (score 0):

To support binary payloads in API Gateway, you must configure the API by adding the media types to the [binaryMediaTypes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/rest-api/#binaryMediaTypes) list of the RestApi resource or set the [contentHandling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#contentHandling) properties on the [Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/) and the [IntegrationResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration-response/) resources.

> Depending on the contentHandling value, and whether the Content-Type
>   header of the response or the Accept header of the incoming request
>   matches an entry in the binaryMediaTypes list, API Gateway can encode
>   the raw binary bytes as a Base64-encoded string, decode a
>   Base64-encoded string back to its raw bytes, or pass the body through
>   without modification.

In simple words, depending you your API Gateway configuration, your form data may or may not be encoded, which needs to be handled in your code when you create a Buffer. Use the second parameter in `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])` to pass corresponding encoding.

Here is the [content type conversion table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html) for your reference.

You can specify the `contentHandling` setting in **serverless.yml** file on the same level as `integration`, for example:

```
integration: LAMBDA
contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
```

Comment: I am the creator of that library, and I'm currently solving the issue with it :)

Comment: There is no problem in parsing.
I sent a file 50Kb,
after parsing I get a buffer 50Kb,
at s3 I get a file 94Kb.

Comment: In the following line `Body: Buffer.from(result[item].content),` is your content encoded? If so, you need to pass the encoding parameter, for example `Buffer.from(result[item].content, 'base64')`.

Comment: It spoils not only media files but text files as well. But I think we are on the right track, there is a problem with encoding.
What can influence all media types except text?

Comment: I modified the answer to address your issue in the way that is related to the API Gateway.

Comment: I didn't get that? where in the settings is that?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is in API Gateway, because I see the input file at request and buffer at lambda are the same size. Lambda got a good file, but s3 saves bad one. Some encoding issue while saving the file.

Comment: Try to add to your serverless.yml right below the "integration" line the "contentHandling" option, like this:

**contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY**

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'm getting
{
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}
with 415 code